# print matrix in R to a file

Tags: r, matrix

I am using R to select the first 2 columns from a file and using a function "table" to make a matrix from it then print it to a file. the problem is that the header is shifted to the left by 1 cell.

The input file is:

```
ExoT    ID3 99.64   1374    5   0   1   1374    15428   16801   0.0 2510
ExoT    ID2 99.64   1374    5   0   1   1374    11168   12541   0.0 2510
ExoT    ID1 99.64   1374    5   0   1   1374    11942   13315   0.0 2510
ExoU    ID3 100.00  2064    0   0   1   2064    1144684 1146747 0.0 3812
ExoU    ID2 100.00  2064    0   0   1   2064    1245564 1247627 0.0 3812
ExoU    ID1 100.00  2064    0   0   1   2064    1156352 1158415 0.0 3812
ExoS    ID1 100.00  2064    0   0   1   2064    1156352 1158415 0.0 3812
```

The desired output is:

```
        ID1 ID2 ID3
  ExoS   1   0   0
  ExoT   1   1   1
  ExoU   1   1   1
```

The actual output is:

```
  ID1 ID2 ID3
  ExoS   1   0   0
  ExoT   1   1   1
  ExoU   1   1   1
```

It seems that a tabb is missing in the begining!

my code is:

```
args <- commandArgs(TRUE)
blast_file <- read.table(args[1])
selected <- subset(blast_file, select = c(V1, V2))
table (selected)
final <- table (selected)
write.table(final,file=args[2],sep="\t")
```

Any Ideas??

Comment: If you put the `col.names = NA` option in your `write.table` call it should fix the disalignment of columns

Comment: that's becaucse `ExoS`and so on are row.names so there is no column header associated...

Comment: @CathG, exactly. Another option is to omit the row names with the `row.names = FALSE`option

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To keep your `row.names` and `col.names` and have a tabb at first, you can export your file in two steps :

first :

```
write.table(c("",colnames(final)),file=args[2],sep="\t")
```

then :

```
write.table(final,file=args[2],sep="\t",col.names=F,append=T,row.names=T)
```