# Keeping the structure of my matrix when writing for use in excel (column headings)

Tags: r, excel, matrix, alignment

I need to be able to keep the row and column headings above the related columns and rows. I export the data using:

```
write.table(Matrix, "Filepath.txt", sep=",", col.names=TRUE, row.names=TRUE, quote=FALSE, na="NA")
```

The structure of the matrix in R is

```
---  Col1  Col2  Col3
Row1  -      -     -
Row2  -      -     -
Row3  -      -     -
```

yet when writing my matrix and opening in Excel I get:

```
Col1  Col2  Col3
Row1  -      -     -
Row2  -      -     -
Row3  -      -     -
```

with no empty cell above the row headings. My matrices are huge so getting into Excel and altering each one manually is not feasible.

Has anyone else encountered this? (I had a quick search through the site and could find no answers) Any solutions to force my desired alignment?

Comment: Replace first column name "Col1" to ",Col1"

Comment: you can see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26656121/print-matrix-in-r-to-a-file/26656727#26656727) for another option using `write.table`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
write.csv(Matrix, "Filepath.txt", row.names=TRUE, quote=FALSE, na="NA")
```

that should fix the first cell problem!